# What is the difference between JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between jQuery and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript)

Would please tell me the difference between Javascript and Jquery? I know about PHP and MySQL. Now,I want to learn JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript is a client-side language, jQuery is a library of javascript functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is built on top of JavaScript.

JavaScript is pretty powerful, but can be difficult to program. jQuery is sort of a wrapper around JavaScript that makes it easier to program.

For example, instead of JavaScript's

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor="#FFF"
```

in jQuery you simply do

```
$('#myDiv').css('background-color','#FFF');
```

jQuery also simplifies stuff like `XMLHttpRequest`s and such like. jQuery allows one to focus on the problem and not worry about what goes on in the underlying JavaScript too much.

That's my half-arsed attempt at explaining things. I'm sure someone can do better!

Answer (score 6):

jQuery was written using JavaScript, and is a library to be used by JavaScript. You cannot learn jQuery without learning JavaScript.

Likely, you'll want to learn and use both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is Javascript's function. It's framework (library), which helps you (from Jquery's moto:) "Write less, do more"

Answer (score 1):

the difference is javascript is a language and jquery is a library created by using javascript...

here is an excellent SO link with learning javascript resources https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a javascript framework that extends a lot of the basic functionality of javascript (better DOM traversal, animation stuff, cross-browser compatibility, etc).

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) gives a good explanation.