# how to use JS to dynamically update innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down box, each option in it has 2 values. I want to dynamically update value in my HTML based on the selection. The value that has to be shown is derived from drop down box values. Here is my code, but nothing seems to be happening here.

```
<html>

    <head><title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var a = new Array();
a[1] = "kgs"; 
a[2] = "gms"; 
a[3] = "ltrs"; 
a[4] = "ml"; 
a[5] = "nos"; 

window.onload = function() {

function updateunit(){

var b = document.getElementById("itemname");

var b1 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

var c = b1.split(',');

var d = c[1];

var e = a[d];

alert(document.write(a[1]));

document.getElementById('pane2').innerHTML = b1 ;

}



updateunit()

document.getElementById('itemname').onchange = updateunit ;

}    

</script></head>


<body>

<form action='production.php' method="POST"> 

Item Name <select name ="itemname" id = "itemname">
<option value = '1,5' > A </option>
<option value = '2,5' > B </option>
<option value = '3,5' > C </option>
<option value = '4,5' > D </option>
</select> <br>



Amount <input type="text" name="amount"> <span id = "pane2"></span> <br>

</form>        

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's `kgs`/`gms`/`ltrs`/`ml`/`nos`? You have to define them. Your code failed to work because there are errors at the beginning, not because it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW please get familiar with jsfiddle :) it's useful

Comment: they are strings..have updated it by putting qoutes. Still nothing is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are trying to achieve this. http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/SbtSF/

1. To get the value of the selected dropdown you just need to elem.value
2. Put the updateunit function as global, not in window.onload function.
3. Arrays starts with index 0. So when spliting don't say c[1], it will give you 5 always, get value from c[0].

Answer (score 0):

```
Javascript is case sensitive
```

Check code syntax   it should be `selectedIndex` --

and plz use this -- `alert(a[1]);` and let me know if its working or not

```
    var a = new Array();
    a[1] = 'kgs'; 
    a[2] = 'gms'; 
    a[3] = 'ltrs'; 
    a[4] = 'ml'; 
    a[5] = 'nos'; 

    window.onload = function() {

    function updateunit(){

    var b = document.getElementById("itemname");

var b1 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;
```

**NEW EDIT**

This is the code i saved under my xampp->htdocs as name.php and the code goes like this and i tested in browser as -- localhost/name.php

```
<?php
/*
I have a drop down box, each option in it has 2 values. I want to dynamically update value in my HTML based on the selection. The value that has to be shown is derived from drop down box values. Here is my code, but nothing seems to be happening here. 
*/
?>

    <html>

        <head><title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

    var a = new Array();
    a[1] = 'kgs'; 
    a[2] = 'gms'; 
    a[3] = 'ltrs'; 
    a[4] = 'ml'; 
    a[5] = 'nos'; 

    window.onload = function() {

    function updateunit(){

    var b = document.getElementById("itemname");

    var b1 = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

    var c = b1.split(',');

    var d = c[1];

    var e = a[d];

    alert(a[1]);

    document.getElementById('pane2').innerHTML = b1 ;

    }



    updateunit()

    document.getElementById('itemname').onchange = updateunit ;

    }    

    </script></head>


    <body>

    <form action='production.php' method="POST"> 

    Item Name <select name ="itemname" id = "itemname">
    <option value = '1,5' > A </option>
    <option value = '2,5' > B </option>
    <option value = '3,5' > C </option>
    <option value = '4,5' > D </option>
    </select> <br>



    Amount <input type="text" name="amount"> <span id = "pane2"></span> <br>

    </form>        

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: @user1545024 check your code once more --- its selectedindex not selectedIndex and another thing  use --  alert(a[1]);

Comment: @user1545024 check im updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = ["kgs", "gms", "ltrs", "ml", "nos"];
window.onload = function() {
    updateunit();
    document.getElementById('itemname').onchange = updateunit;
}
function updateunit(evt) {
    var b1 = evt.target.value;
    if(b1) {
        var d = b1.split(',')[1];
        var e = a[d - 1];
        document.getElementById('pane2').innerHTML = e ;
    }  

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of :

```
document.getElementById('pane2').innerHTML = b1 ;
```

Use :

```
document.getElementById('pane2').html(b1);
```

Reference : 
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: That's Jquery, [Jquery and Javascript are not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707395/what-is-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: Please don't mix-up js with jQuery